# NodeJS Splitting line delimited string into object

Tags: regex, node.js

I'm loading contents of a file that looks like this:

```
one-apple
two-banana
three-orange
```

And I would like to get a key-value object returned. Here's what I have so far but it just returns an empty object:

```
var regex = /([\\w-]+)\\-([\\w-]+)/g;
var match, results = {};

while((match = regex.exec(data)) !== null){
   results[match[1]] = match[2];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing that is wrong in your code is regexp. It should be:

```
var regex = /([\w-]+)\-([\w-]+)/g;
```

`\\` in regexp means `\` symbol itself. So, `[\\w]` means `\` or `w` and not `[a-zA-Z_]` as you expected.

There is only one reason to escape each `\` symbol - if you want to store regexp in a string. So, the following code will work too:

```
var regex = new RegExp('([\\w-]+)\\-([\\w-]+)', 'g');
```